# how i use the accnum from 1st query in the next sub queries

Tags: oracle

**How i use the accnum from 1st query in the next sub queries**

```
select * from (select a.accnum from cb1090 a where a.accnum='123456'
union all
select max(d.depdate) from cb1340 d where a.accnum=d.ACCNUM
union all
select max(e.depdate) from cb1360 e where a.accnum=e.ACCNUM)
```

Comment: What are trying to do? Sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: i want to retrive the depdate from table 1340 where accnum is 123456 which is come from the table 1090

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JOINS`..
I see you `UNION` date and `accnum` , which *don't* seem valid.
Hope you need something like below!

```
select max(d.depdate) 
from cb1340 d,cb1090 a
where a.accnum = d.ACCNUM -- Is it a.accnum you join again with d.accnum or a.other_column ??
 and a.accnum = '123456'
union all
select max(e.depdate)
from cb1360 e,cb1090 a
where a.accnum = e.ACCNUM 
and a.accnum = '123456'
```